# How to perform a method in model only if the controller action is create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Question is in my rails app I have method called range days I only want this to work if the controller action is create_half how can I do this? any help would be greatly appreciated!!

This is my entry model

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.primary_key = 'id'

  //This is what I want to only happen when my controller action is create_half 
  def range_days
    self.range_days = only_weekdays(leave_start.to_date..(leave_end.to_date)).to_d 
  end
```

This is my entry controller

```
 class EntryController < ApplicationController


   def half_day
     @entry = Entry.new
     render :half_day
   end
```

Comment: What did you mean by `This is what I want to only happen when my controller action is create_half` ? `range_days` is an instance method and is available for any instance of `Entry`.

Comment: yes @Sharvy Ahmed how could I make range_days only available to create?

Comment: I would not recommend calling the method the same thing as one of you attributes. This has now become veiled assignment and will reset `range_days` every time it is called. This will make debugging in the future very confusing.

Comment: so if i changed the name of range_days method i could then call it only on create correct?

Comment: Do not keep attribute and method name same. You will fall into infinite loop if you try to call that attribute from inside of that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your attribute name from `range_days` to something else. Otherwise you won't be able to get the value in `range_days` action.

`self.range_days` in `range_days` method will call the `range_days` method again instead of the `range_days` attribute. As a result it will become an infinite loop and you will get a **Stack Level Too Deep** exception.

Then you can simply do the following in your controller:

```
def create_half 
  @entry = Entry.new
  @entry.range_days
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for a railsy way to do this. Its not needed:

```
class EntryController < ApplicationController
  def create_half
    @entry = Entry.new.range_days
    #other stuff
  end
end
```

Should do you fine.

Comment: I get this error when trying your answeapp/controllers/entry_controller.rb:60: syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting ')' @entry = Entry.new.t_days ^

Comment: The syntax error is in your code, not my example. Post the code if you haven't found it yet.